# Regex for password like google registration?

Tags: php, regex, laravel

Im using laravel and I want to allow password that must have atleast 1 from each of the following categories:

1. a-z or A-Z (alphabets)
2. 0-9 (digits)
3. Special symbol (!@#$ ......) (All symbols just like google)

Can someone give a regex expression for this as I dont know how regex works.

I have tried this:

```
^.*(?=.{3,})(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[\d\X])(?=.*[`~!@#$%^&*()-_=+[]{}|;:",<.>\/?]).*$
```

But i dont understand what `(?=.{3,})` does and also its not working as I would expect

I will test the expression on https://regex101.com/. So I hope you test it there first before posting the answer.

Comment: Hi Raj, could you please spend a minute to read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and update your question?

Comment: no problem I will update my question

Comment: If you are unsure of how a regex works, I would recommend looking it up and study it.

Comment: Try: `/^(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*\W)\S+$/`